# export is not working when try to destructure in javascript import

Tags: javascript

I have two file:
file A.js:

```
export default={
    name:"sample"
  }
```

file B.svelte:

```
import {name} from './A';
```

Error:
name is not export from A.js

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems there:

1. That's now how you make the default export an object, you should remove the `=`.
2. `import` is not destructuring, they just have a superficial resemblance to each other. You can't destructure during an import.

I would make the export a named export:

```
export let name = "sample";
```

...which would work with your import. Changes to `name` by the source module will show up in the imported binding for it (imports are live bindings to the original export).

But if you don't want to do that, here's how you export an object as the default export:

```
export default {
    name: "sample",
};
```

and then you have to import and destructure separately:

```
import obj from "./A.js";
const { name } = obj;
```

**Note:** The above is how standard JavaScript modules work according to specification. Bundlers may go beyond the spec when bundling code (for instance, may allow named import syntax when in fact you're destructuring a default exported objects), but if so, it's non-standard.

Comment: When I am using with 
module.exports={}
It is working But not I moving on ES Module.

Comment: @Ramsay - The above works with standard JavaScript modules. If it's not working in your environment, then either you've made a slight mistake implementing the above in your code, or your bundler is doing something non-standard. (It seems unlikely to me your bundler would be getting this wrong; *mostly* they just do additional things, rather than getting basic things wrong.)

Comment: @Ramsay - [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-71218686-zwj4bb) the version with the object as a default export. [Here's](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-question-71218686-hvw34i) the version with the named export (which I would recommend).