# How to succinctly export a wrapped and named function without using two names

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a function which transforms other functions:

```
//library:
let transform = function(OriginalComponent) {
  let WrappedComponent (props) => {
    //some transformation 
    return <OriginalComponent {...props} />
  };
  //I specifically need the original component to have a NON EMPTY name here
    Object.defineProperty(WrappedComponent, "name", { value: OriginalComponent.name });
}
```

I currently use this in a file like so

```
export const MyWrappedComponent = transform(function MyComponent(props){
  return <h1>Hello {props.name}!</h1>;
});
```

With this setup I currently need to use *different names* for the export *and* the function.

My question is: **Can I somehow export this in one line, using just one name instead of two?**

I tried:

```
export function transform(function MyComponent(props){ 
  return <h1>Hello {props.name}!</h1>;
});
```

But that is not valid, as the export has no name.

I also thought of

```
export const MyComponent = transform((props) => {
  return <h1>Hello {props.name}!</h1>;
});
```

But then `transform()` receives an unnamed component (and it cannot know the export name I believe?)

This is regarding the standards of a library, so I want to keep the example as clean as possible. Naming a function and then naming the export could get confusing. If I have to name both, I'd prefer to use the same name, but I don't see how.

Comment: You could make it an default export and that would not require keeping a name

Comment: *"But I don't need the export to be named, just the function that's being wrapped."* What do you mean by that? Do you want it to be the default export of the module?

Comment: In your example you've used `MyWrappedComponent` and `MyComponent`, but you said you only want one name. Which one do you want? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are correct, needed a `=>`. And I just want one name, doesn't matter which one. @Gibz Default export would indeed solve this! Although I recently moved all code to named exports after reading [this](https://blog.neufund.org/why-we-have-banned-default-exports-and-you-should-do-the-same-d51fdc2cf2ad) which solved some issues with automatically finding the right imports in code editors. If there's no other solution I'll consider trying this, thanks both

Comment: Re your edit: *"With this setup I currently need to use different names for the export and the function."* There's nothing in that code that requires you to use different names, `export const MyComponent = transform(function MyComponent(props){ /*...*/ });` is perfectly valid. I'm glad to hear you're trying to avoid default exports, I think they're quite a bad idea. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right! Somehow must have missed this or got confused trying many different things. I think this will be the best solution then. Creators of these components will need to write the name twice, but it can be the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a named export, and you want to pass the function directly into `transform`, you can't (reasonably¹) get around repeating the name, like this:

```
export const MyComponent = transform(function MyComponent(props){
    return <h1>Hello {props.name}!</h1>;
});
```

> With this setup I currently need to use different names for the export and the function.

Thankfully, you don't; it's perfectly valid to use the same name there, as above.

---

For what it's worth, there are a couple of issues with the `transform` function that I noticed:

1. You can't directly write to the `name` property of a function, it's read-only. But you can *replace* the property (because it's configurable) via `Object.defineProperty`.
2. It's not *returning* the wrapped component.

Here's a version with those fixed:

```
export let transform = function (OriginalComponent) {
    let WrappedComponent = (props) => {
        //some transformation
        return <OriginalComponent {...props} />;
    };
    // I specifically need the original component to have a NON EMPTY name here
    Object.defineProperty(WrappedComponent, "name", {
        value: OriginalComponent.name,
    });
    return WrappedComponent;
};
```

In that `Object.defineProperty` call, I haven't specified any of the flags (`writable`, `configurable`, `enumerable`), so the flags from the previous property will be used. (The property is `configurable` but not `writable` or `enumerable`.)

---

As an alternative, you could put the unwrapped components in an object:

```
export const components = {
    MyComponent(props) {
        return <h1>Hello ${props.name}!</h1>;
    },
    // ...
};
```

...and then post-process them:

```
for (const [name, component] of Object.entries(components)) {
    components[name] = transform(component);
}
```

But it means that your export is the `components` object, not the individual components, so you'd end up with usage like this:

```
import { components } from "./somewhere";
const { MyComponent } = components;
// ...
```

...which is less than ideal. (And sadly, you can't directly [destructure imports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71218730/157247).)